# Ordinary differential equation similar to Baer equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve (analytically) an ODE for $x \in ]0,1[$:
$$x(1-x)\frac{d^2}{dx^2}u+(1+2δ-2δx)\frac{d}{dx}u+(δ-α+αx)u=0,$$
where $α$ and $δ$ constants. This is similar to [Baer equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BaerDifferentialEquation.html) and to Mathieu as well, but I could not find one of both cases for the equation above. (Tried lot of different manipulations on $x$ or $u$ unsuccessfully).

When $α =0$ this is the hypergeometric differential equation (not the case here).

Could anyone give a hint?

Answer (score 1):

Maple says the solutions are
$$u \left( x \right) =c_{{1}}{\it HeunC} \left( 0,2\,\delta,-2,-\alpha,1
+\alpha,x \right) +c_{{2}}{x}^{-2\,\delta}{\it HeunC} \left( 0,-2\,
\delta,-2,-\alpha,1+\alpha,x \right) 
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you by chance test if there is a solution in $\delta$ for the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} HeunC_{1 or 2}=0$?

Comment: The differential equation has a regular singular point at $x=1$ with indicial roots $0$ and $2$.  There is then a solution corresponding to the root $2$, which is a series of the form $ (x-1)^2 + c_3 (x-1)^3 + \ldots$.  I'm not sure how to express this in terms of the HeunC functions.